# How can I automatically change the version number in the setup.py file?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I am packaging a django app in "whl" format with `python setup.py bdist_wheel` command.
setup.py:

```
setup(
    name="myapp",
    description="Test app",
    python_requires='>=3.7',

    version="0.1",

    include_package_data=True,
    zip_safe=False,
    packages=find_packages(include=['myapp', 'myapp.*']),
    install_requires=base_requirements,
    extras_require={
        'with_zmq': ['pyzmq'],
    },
    license="Not open source",
    setup_requires=setup_requirements,
....
    )
```

How can I automatically increment the version number every time I run `python setup.py bdist_wheel` ?

Are there any libraries for this purpose?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can implement this logic yourself directly into the `setup.py` script. Maybe something like: read the file names in the `dist` directory, extract the old version number out of the file names, increment this number and set it as argument to the `version` parameter of the `setup()` function call. -- Maybe there are some "plugins" that already do this. If I were you I would check [*setuptools-scm*](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools-scm/) and other plugins like this.

Comment: See e.g. https://github.com/python-versioneer/python-versioneer

Comment: Thank you @sinoroc. setuptools-scm is very similar to what I need.